# jQuery, manipulating a global object through function (unexpected result?)

Tags: jquery, arrays

Sorry for the vague title but not sure how to put it.

So if I have an object (which contains an array(X)) that I pass as data in a click event that triggers a function. The function creates a new variable(Y) referencing the array in the object passed. If I then push a new value to that array variable(Y) it manipulates the original array(X) not just the newly created one(Y). 
Weird explanation, think easiest is to see [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mj386ntb/) I created to showcase the whole thing.

My question is, why does it manipulate the original array in the object? (Looking at the code, I would understand if it was manipulated if I pushed directly to `e.data.testdata.testarray` but why does it do that when I'm pushing to the newly created reference variable(Y)).

Testcode:

```
$(function() {
 function testManipulate (e) {
    alert(e.data.testdata.testarray);
    var scopedTestArray = e.data.testdata.testarray,
            newValue = 'test3';

    scopedTestArray.push(newValue);
    alert(e.data.testdata.testarray);
 }

 var testObj = {
    testarray: ['test1', 'test2']
 };

 $('.js-test').on('click', {testdata: testObj}, testManipulate);
});
```

Comment: Both variables are a *reference* to where the array is stored in memory, hence they point to the same thing when you copy them. Search for array cloning. There's lots of answers covering this.

Comment: The full content of your question must be **in** your question, not just linked. Links rot, making the question and its answers useless to people in the future, and people shouldn't have to go off-site to help you. Put a [mcve] **in** the question, ideally using Stack Snippets (the `<>` toolbar button) to make it runnable. More: [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Thanks @RoryMcCrossan, sounds correct.
And yeah, didnt know how to formulate the question in a good way...sorry for that, would gladly take a better title if anyone wants to fomulate it better.

Comment: There's only one array in memory, the two variables both point to it.  This is called "reference variables".  For anything other than a simple primitive value, to create a second in-memory copy you'd need to manually create a new object (or array) and copy the data to it.

Comment: Aye, thanks. Didnt know I had to first create say an empty array and then add the event data to that and push to it in order to not manipulate the original one.

Answer (score 0):

I hope you need this

```
$(function() {
    var testObj = {
        testarray: ['test1', 'test2']
    };
    $('.js-test').on('click',function (e) {
        newValue = 'test'+(testObj.testarray.length+1);
        testObj.testarray.push(newValue); // you can access testObj here because scope of sub block.
        alert(testObj.testarray);
    });
});

// alert(testObj.testarray); you can not access here because it out of scope
```

Actually I didn't get your question properly, don't consider this answer if I am wrong.

Comment: This is jsfiddle link with updated code https://jsfiddle.net/mj386ntb/1/